# Правильная нумерация ol li через псевдоэлемент с учетом атрибута start

Tags: css, вёрстка

Знающие css-гуру, подскажите как можно решить данную дилемму:

[image: атрибут указывает с какого числа продолжить нумерацию, но через before срабатывает некорректно]

CSS прилагаю:

```
.text_block ol {
    counter-reset: li;
}

.text_block ol li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 34px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.text_block ol li:before {
    color: var(--color2);
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: counter(li)'.';
    counter-increment: li;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При определении кастомных счетчиков атрибут `start` не имеет смысла. Мы же убираем стандартную нумерацию.

В Вашем случае начальное значение нумерации нужно задавать через свойство `counter-reset: li 5`

Результат:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: li 5;
}

ol li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 34px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol li:before {
  color: var(--color2);
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: counter(li)'.';
  counter-increment: li;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Получается тут никак изящно не решить проблему( Придется цепляться к классу у ol, дабы не хардкодить counter-reset у всех списков.